# external harddrive - USB 2.0 for (L)Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a Lenovo PC (System Information: Manufacturer: LENOVO, Product Name: 10159, Version: Lenovo H520e, Family: IdeaCentre).
I´m running WIN 8.1 (64bit) on it.

What I want to do is connect an external harddrive to it via USB 2.0, preferably Western Digital 1TB Elements  WDBUZG0010BBK (or a Toshiba STOR.E ALU 2S, 500 GB).
From this I want to power up a Linux-system (Lubuntu or Ubuntu).

As no external power supply is needed for those harddrives I wonder what the specifcations with respect to power consumption are. I mean can I just plug it in
and be fine running Linux from that.

As far as I know specifications for USB 2.0 are:
5V and 500mA. Which means 2.5 watts.  Would that be sufficient for my purposes?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Greetings.
Rosika

Comment: If you can use it as an external hard drive, you should be able to boot from it, whatever the power specifications.

Comment: You may need to try. I have used such drives, and they sometimes start too slow to be recognized and booted from. Better try a drive with extra power supply.

Comment: Tnx for your replies. I´ve been usig the Toshiba HD as backup medium and have never had any difficulties in powering it up. I´ll give it a try as boot-medium first.